# are all continuous convex functions increasing?

Tags: terminology, convex-optimization

Hi

My question is about convex functions

I've been reading Boyd's convex optimization and a question came to me.
I guess if $f$ is a convex function then $f$ is increasing .

I guess it is conceptually but I didn't find a mathemathical theorem to prove it .

What constraints that we assume makes the gusse be true ?

I would appreciate any counter examples or constraints  :)

And I mean by an increasing definition that $f$ is increasing if : $a \ge b$ then $f(a) \ge f(b)$

And also assume that $f$ is continuous

Comment: No, they can be decreasing then increasing.

Comment: Consider $e^{-x}.$

Answer (score 5):

No consider a continuous convex increasing function $f$.  Then $g:x\mapsto f(-x)$ is  a convex decreasing function.  This is because a mirror transformation on points $a$ and $b$ will keep the mirrored graph of $f$ below the mirrored segment $[(a,f(a)),(b,f(b))]$, but obviously a mirrored increasing graph becomes decreasing.  For example consider $e^{-x}$.

You can even be non-monotonic.  Consider something like $x^2$.

For functions of class $\mathcal C^2(\mathbb R)$, what convexity means though, is that *your tangent will all raise*.  So once it becomes increasing, the function cannot become decreasing later; that would give you a smaller derivative.

Comment: I think for $C^2$ class of convex functions, you have the result that they're either monotonous or break in two monotonous parts.

Comment: Fixed to reflect that I'm speaking of class $\mathcal C^2$ over $\mathbb R$, not some weird disconnected subset.